# Multiple text input fields text get into the <textarea>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to make some live editing option i will try to show you what i want.

For example i have 4 text input fields and one textarea.

```
<input type="text" name="fname">

<input type="text" name="lname">

<input type="text" name="fname">

<input type="text" name="company">

<textarea></textarea>
```

I want these text input fields data show into textarea lively.and also have line brakes between two inputs.

Comment: What if the user types into the textarea?

Comment: When user type in the input fields this text should display in textarea.

Comment: Right, but what if the user types into the *textarea*?

Comment: Just user can use text input fields for text.

Comment: Maybe you should add a `readonly` attribute to the `textarea` then.

Comment: Or don't use a textarea at all. You can dynamically set the text content of *any* element, so there's no need to use an element designed for input if you don't want input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Really quick and dirty:

```
$("input[type='text'], textarea").keyup(function() {
    $("textarea").val('')
    var tev = '';
    $("input[type='text']").each(function() {
        tev += $(this).val() + '\n';
    });
    $("textarea").val(tev);
});
```

Comment: "You'll want keyup, not keydown." :P

Comment: Umm - it has been for quite a while now.

Comment: That's not what the updated fiddle in your answer says.

Comment: Oh man, that's not even my fiddle! Hahaha!

Comment: That's why I put that first comment. That's okay, I laughed too lol.

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

HTML:

```
<input type="text" name="fname" id="i1">

<input type="text" name="lname" id="i2">

<input type="text" name="fname" id="i3">

<input type="text" name="company" id="i4">

<textarea id="i5"></textarea>
```

JS:

```
$( function() {
    function updateTextarea() {
        $( '#i5' ).val( $( '#i1' ).val() + '\n\n' + $( '#i2' ).val() + '\n\n' + $( '#i3' ).val() + '\n\n' + $( '#i4' ).val() );
    }
    $( '#i1, #i2, #i3, #i4' ).keyup( updateTextarea );
});
```

[jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/XLMvb/)

Comment: You'll want keyup, not keydown.

Answer (score 0):

Or in vanilla JS:

```
(function(){
    var fname = document.getElementsByName("fname")[0];
        fname.onkeyup=setTextareaValue;
    var lname = document.getElementsByName("lname")[0];
        lname.onkeyup=setTextareaValue;
    var fnamex = document.getElementsByName("fnamex")[0]; //you had two elements named fname
        fnamex.onkeyup=setTextareaValue;
    var company = document.getElementsByName("company")[0];
        company.onkeyup=setTextareaValue;
    var textarea = document.getElementsByName("textarea")[0];

    function setTextareaValue(){
        textarea.value = ""+fname.value+"\n"+lname.value+"\n"+fnamex.value+"\n"+company.value;
    }

})();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/LFfEf/

Answer (score 0):

You could build a reuseable jQuery function to do this wherever you've grouped inputs in a fieldset:

HTML:

```
<fieldset data-concat-into="concatinated">
    <input type="text" name="fname" />
    <input type="text" name="lname" />
    <input type="text" name="fname" />
    <input type="text" name="company" />
</fieldset>
<textarea id="concatinated" name="textarea" readonly="readonly" rows="10"></textarea>
```

jQuery:

```
$("fieldset[data-concat-into] input").on("keyup", function(){
    var fieldset = $(this).parent();
    var target = fieldset.data("concat-into");
    var vals = "";
    fieldset.children("input").each(function(){
        vals += ((vals)?"\n":"")+ $(this).val();
    });
    $("#"+target).val(vals);
});
```

Obligatory JSFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/JpagC/